# Generic Json To Object transformer

Tags: spring-integration

Is there any way to set the value of "type" attribute of a JsonToObject transformer dynamically ?
For ex, A message header will tell you the target Java Object to which incoming Json payload should be converted to.
Something like,

```
<int:json-to-object-transformer 
    input-channel="jsonTransformationChannel" type="headers['targetJavaObject']"
    output-channel="payloadTransformationChannel" />
```

NOTE : "type" attribute does not support SpEL expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 3, the JTOT uses similar headers to the Spring AMQP JSON message converters. See [`JsonHeaders`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mapping/support/JsonHeaders.java#L39).

For a simple type, set the `json__TypeId__` header to the fully qualified class name and **do not** configure a `type`.